# Code execution not linear (?) in D3 for loop

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm doing a pretty trivial thing in D3, but I'm running into weird issues with the order of code execution. I'm taking an array of image names, looping through them, and adding each `svg` to a parent `svg` as a `g` element. All that works great. Here's the code that's doing so:

```
var names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
var over = d3.select('#overlay');
var w = 20;
for (var i = names.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var x = w * i + w
  console.log('1. '+ x)
  d3.xml(names[i]+'.svg', function(error, xml) {
    console.log('2. '+ x)
    over.append('g')
    .attr('transform','translate('+ x +','+ 20 +')')
    .html(xml.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].innerHTML)
  })
}
```

However, I'm running into issues with the transforms all being the same, and decided to log x to check it out. The log should be this:

```
1. 60
2. 60
1. 40
2. 40
1. 20
2. 20
```

Instead, it's logging this:

```
1. 60
1. 40
1. 20
2. 20
2. 20
2. 20
```

What could possibly be making this run out of order like that?? Is the `d3.xml` call asynchronous? I can't figure it out.

Comment: `d3.xml()` is asynchronous function and is not started in sequence as you expect but little later which is enough that loop is over and x has value 20.

Comment: Great... any way to force it to be synchronous? Or to block until it's done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d3.xml()` is asynchronous function and is not started in sequence as expected but little later which is enough that loop is over and `x` has value 20.

You have to make closure for value `x` using for example:

```
  (function (x) {
      d3.xml(names[i]+'.svg', function(error, xml) {
        console.log('2. '+ x)
        over.append('g')
        .attr('transform','translate('+ x +','+ 20 +')')
        .html(xml.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].innerHTML)
      });
  })(x)
```

That way you will get in console log:

```
1. 60
1. 40
1. 20
2. 60
2. 40
2. 20
```